# Dart Built Value Deserialize List of Objects

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an API that's returning a list of objects...

```
[{}, {}, {}, ...]
```

I already have a defined and working [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart) model for each object. However, now I need to deserialize the list.

I currently am trying something like this:

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> json = JSON.decode(DEMO_TASK);
 json.expand<Task>((Map<String, dynamic> map) => _serializers.deserializeWith<Task>(Task.serializer, map));
```

However, that causes issues since it says `_serializers.deserializeWith` return type `Task` isn't an `Iterable<Task>` as defined by the closure.

How do I go about deserializing the list. I'm sure I'm missing something super basic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yup. I missed something basic. I was thinking I was using a stream, but since it's a list you just have to use the `.map` function on a list.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> json = JSON.decode(DEMO_TASK);
    List<Task> tasks = json.map<Task>((Map<String, dynamic> map) => _serializers.deserializeWith<Task>(Task.serializer, map)).toList();
```

Answer (score 21):

In case you want to have more general approach you can use this code snippet:
In case anybody needs this functionality I leave here code snippet of how to handle this situation (code should be placed in `serializers.dart` file):

```dart
Serializers standardSerializers = (serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();

T deserialize<T>(dynamic value) =>
    standardSerializers.deserializeWith<T>(standardSerializers.serializerForType(T), value);

BuiltList<T> deserializeListOf<T>(dynamic value) =>
    BuiltList.from(value.map((value) => deserialize<T>(value)).toList(growable: false));
```

So if you have json file

```
[
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "result": "success"
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "result": "fail"
  }
]
```

And built value class:

```dart
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';

part 'test_class.g.dart';

abstract class TestClass implements Built<TestClass, TestClassBuilder> {

  String get name;
  String get result;

  TestClass._();

  factory TestClass([updates(TestClassBuilder b)]) = _$TestClass;

  static Serializer<TestClass> get serializer => _$testClassSerializer;

}
```

You can use method `deserializeListOf`  from above as:

```dart
import 'package:path_to_your_serializers_file/serializers.dart';

final BuiltList<TestClass> listOfTestClasses = deserializeListOf<TestClass>(json);
```

Comment: json is not a string, it is a list because <<JSON.decode(DEMO_TASK)>> was used.

Comment: I'm having issues with this code, I'm guessing due to later versions of Dart. I've outlined them on what I'm guessing is your same response to a related git issue: https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/565#issuecomment-1132439225
Any ideas?